# Rails3 and readline problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, readline

I'm using rails3 for the first time (i've been using rails2 for years) inside an rvm.  Trying to start the console, i get this error:

`require': no such file to load -- readline`

I've googled around and this seems to be a common problem.  Most solutions seem to involve 1) installing the following: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libreadline5-dev`
2) going to the gem folder for readline, running `ruby extconf.rb` which generates a makefile 
3) doing `make` and `make install`

Now, i didn't have readline installed in my rvm, so i tried to install it.  But couldn't work out what the gem is: `gem install readline` doesn't give any results.  The only one i found was `gem install rdp-rb-readline`.  I installed the two dev libraries, installed the rdp-rb-readline gem, went to the subsequent gem folder, and ran `ruby extconf.rb`.  This did indeed generate a makefile. But i can't `make` it or `make install`:  i get these errors:

`max-laptop:readline$ make
cc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux -I. -DHAVE_READLINE_READLINE_H -DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY_H -DHAVE_RL_FILENAME_COMPLETION_FUNCTION -DHAVE_RL_USERNAME_COMPLETION_FUNCTION -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES -DHAVE_RL_DEPREP_TERM_FUNCTION -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER -DHAVE_RL_BASIC_WORD_BREAK_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETER_WORD_BREAK_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_BASIC_QUOTE_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETER_QUOTE_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_FILENAME_QUOTE_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_ATTEMPTED_COMPLETION_OVER -DHAVE_RL_LIBRARY_VERSION -DHAVE_RL_EVENT_HOOK -DHAVE_RL_CLEANUP_AFTER_SIGNAL -DHAVE_RL_CLEAR_SIGNALS -DHAVE_RL_VI_EDITING_MODE -DHAVE_RL_EMACS_EDITING_MODE -DHAVE_REPLACE_HISTORY_ENTRY -DHAVE_REMOVE_HISTORY  -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -c readline.c
readline.c: In function ‘readline_readline’:
readline.c:82: error: ‘rb_io_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:82: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:82: error: for each function it appears in.)
readline.c:82: error: ‘ofp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:82: error: ‘ifp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [readline.o] Error 1`

Kind of stuck now.  Am i missing something else fundamental that i need to make the required libraries/gem/whatever?

Grateful for any advice - max

SOLUTION:
I actually just solved this - i uninstalled the rdp-rb-readline gem, then did `gem install rb-readline`, then added `gem 'rb-readline'` to my app's Gemfile.  I guess it just needed to know where to look for the readline stuff if it wasn't  in the usual place.  I didn't need to do anything with extconf.rb, which is good because the rb-readline gem doesn't have one.

I've left this at the end of my question because a) someone else might have a better understanding of the problem rather than my trial and error approach and b) in case anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: I actually just solved this - solution added to OP

Comment: where was the "subsequent gem folder" ?

Comment: @rogerdpack - i don't have it anymore but it would have been `/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rdp-rb-readline-<version>`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `rvm`, you can always make use of the package installer facility to fix any issues your OS may have. Ruby often uses libraries that are a bit different from what you have installed:

```
rvm package install readline
```

The `rvm` installer applies several patches against a specific, known-working version of readline and should build without issues. This readline package won't affect your system install, and is used only for rvm-based builds.

Comment: Thanks tadman - i just tried that and it seemed to happily go through the installation process.  But i still get the same problem.  I found another solution, i don't know if that's any better, which i appended to my OP.  But i like your approach better and would like to get it working properly.

Comment: As a note, you need to build your `ruby` against the rvm-managed readline for this to work properly using `rvm install`.

Comment: Sorry tadman, i don't quite understand what you mean.  Could you provide more details?  Thanks!

Comment: If you install the `readline` package after you've build Ruby, it has no effect. You must rebuild Ruby with the `readline` package installed for it to be linked in properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-X.X.X-pXXX/ext/readline
```

(replace ruby-1.9.2-p180 with your system ruby version)

```
ruby extconf.rb
```

if any checking says no, install these pakages:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libreadline5-dev
```

and  run `ruby extconf.rb`

you should get all checking yes,

```
make
make install
```

now it will work.

Comment: its not working though in my case.. so I went with that gem 'rb-readline'

Comment: Above works perfectly, thank you. `sudo yum install readline-devel` for CentOS.